# Plotting Canmaps line data in R

Tags: r, plot, arcgis, shapefile

I am new to using R and am working with a shape file from the DMTI Canmap dataset: http://www.dmtispatial.com/canmap/#top

I have been successful importing the shape file as a 'SpatialLineDataFrame' using readOGR. I have been unsuccessful in mapping the data. Here is what I have tried so far. Note: I have named the data frame 'trans'.

```
library(maps)
library(rgdal)
```

1 Plotting the longitude and latitude coordinates

```
plot(trans$LONGITUDE,trans$LATITUDE)
```

This command plots the coordinates as points not lines. I'd like to map the lines.

2 Using ggmap to plot

```
library(ggmap)
can <- get_map(location="canada",zoom=3)
ggmap(can) + geom_point(data=trans, aes(x="LONGITUDE",y="LATITUDE"))
```

This returns an error saying 'Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale'

```
ggmap(can) + geom_path(data=trans, aes(x="LONGITUDE",y="LATITUDE"))
```

This also returns an error saying 'Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale'

As a heads-up, when I ask for the names of the data stored in 'trans' I get these names: "UID"        "NAME"       "TYPE"       "LOCATION"   "NUM_LINES"  "MUNICIPAL"  "PROV"      "LONGITUDE"  "LATITUDE"   "BEGELEV"    "ENDELEV"    "ACCURACY"   "ACQ_TECH"   "VALDATE"   "PROVIDER"   "SHAPE_Leng"

Are there packages or commands you would recommend trying in order to map the lines stored in this .shp file using R?

Comment: remove the quote marks around `"LONGITUDE"` and `"LATITUDE"`

Comment: I tried that and received this message "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'LONGITUDE' not found"

Comment: I did some more digging around and found a way to get the data to plot. I used the 'maptools' package and used: trans_lines <- readShapeLines("filepath") and then plot(trans_lines).